# Clean up "browse other questions tagged"

Tags: feature-request, questions, design

The designers are doing a great job cleaning up all the sites with their css expertise!  One thing that seems to bug me is the bottom portion (before the footer) where we state:

**Not the answer you're looking for?  Browse other questions tagged [insert tags here] or ask your own question.**

[image]

Is it possible for this to not take up two lines.  Maybe get rid of the "Not the answer you're lookin for?"  And just have

Browse other questions in [tag1] [tag2]... to max out at one line.  It seems that it would fit nicely with one line.  Kind of like the recent request we got regarding the tags on the new homepage with the tabs.

I also pointed out the question feed, it just seems odd there but I don't know what to do with it.  Does anyone even use feeds anymore?